# What shell does std::system use?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, sh

**TL;DR;** I guess the shell that `std::system` use, is `sh`. But, I'm not sure.

I tried to print the shell, using this code: `std::system("echo $SHELL")`, and the output was `/bin/bash`. It was weird for me. So, I wanted to see, what happens if I do that in `sh`? And, the same output: `/bin/bash`. Also, if I use a command like `SHELL="/usr/bin/something"`, to set the `SHELL` variable to another string, it will print the new string that I set to it (`/usr/bin/something`), and it looks it's not a good way to see what shell it's using. Then, I tried to check it, using the `ps` command, and the output was: `bash`, `a.out`, `ps`. It was weird to see `bash` in this list. So, I created a custom shell, and change the shell in gnome-terminal to it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    while (true)
    {
        std::string command;
        std::getline(std::cin, command);
        std::system(command.c_str());
    }
}
```

[image]

Now, it's easier to test, and I think, the results is better.

Then, I tried to test the `ps` command again, but in the custom shell, and the results was: `test_shell`, `ps`.

It was weird again. How the shell isn't `sh`, nor `bash`? And, the final test I did was: `echo $0`. And, the results was `sh`, in both custom shell, and normal program.

**Edit**

It seems like `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash` (`ll /bin/sh` command's output is `/bin/sh -> bash`), and actually, it seems like the only difference between `sh` and `bash` is filename, and the files's contents are the same. I checked the difference between these files with `diff` command too:

```
$ xxd /bin/sh > sh
$ xxd /bin/bash > bash
$ diff sh bash
```

(+ Yes, `$SHELL` doesn't means the running shell (I didn't know that when I was testing, and I just wanted to see what happens))

Comment: $SHELL is set to the user's default (login) shell, not the current running shell.

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I expected that it's not a good way to find the current shell. Actually, I tested and tried multiple, and a lot ways.

Comment: Exhaustive answer is in man 3 system. /bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash.

Comment: Just run your program under `strace -f` if you want to see what shell is executed, or have it start a long-running program and then use `ps` to find its parent from a terminal.

Comment: @273K Yes, it seems it's true (used `ll /bin/sh`, and the output was `/bin/sh -> bash`). But it seems they are different too. idk how

Comment: Bash gets the called name in argv[0] and depending on the name sh or bash may apply different settings and enable different set of shell extensions. It's widely used technique, look at grep, egrep, fgrep, vim, evim, vi...

Comment: @273K I found out how. `bash`/`sh` are running something, that it (the "something") detects, if the program that is running's name is `bash`, run bash, else, run `sh`

Comment: @273K https://imgur.com/a/D1IbWrk (`bash` is copied from `/bin/bash` (`cp /bin/bash .`))

Comment: SHELL isn't even necessarily the user's default login shell.  It's just a value that the user can set in their environment to inform other programs which shell they prefer.  In that sense it's no different than PAGER or EDITOR.

Comment: @WilliamPursell OK. I just wanted to say that case too.

Comment: When you run just one command (*e.g.*, `ps`) in the shell, it may **replace** itself with that command and thus vanish from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU sources (https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/system.c) say

```
/bin/sh
```

So, whatever `/bin/sh` is hardlinked to is the shell invoked by `std::system()` on Linux.

(This is correct, as `/bin/sh` is expected to be linked to a sane shell capable of doing things with the system.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system), `std::system`

> calls the host environment's command processor (e.g. `/bin/sh`, `cmd.exe`, `command.com`)

This means the shell used will depend on the operating system.

On any POSIX OS (including Linux), the shell used by `std::system` is `/bin/sh`. (Though as the OP points out, `/bin/sh` could be a symlink to another shell.)

As for the `SHELL` environment variable, as has been pointed out in the comments, this environment variable cannot be used to reliably identify the running shell program. `SHELL` is defined by POSIX to

> represent a pathname of the user's preferred command language interpreter

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html))</sup>